# React native app crash after that I installed it with apk (with some warnings)

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to run a react native app. In the terminal I ran `npx react-native init rn8`, then I open android Studio to upgrade AGP to version 7.1.3 and I also set `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip` in the file `rn8\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`. So I run `npm run android` and I have this warning:

```
 Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libbutter.so, libc++_shared.so, libevent-2.1.so, libevent_core-2.1.so, libevent_extra-2.1.so, libfabricjni.so, libfb.so, libfbjni.so, libflipper.so, libfolly_futures.so, libfolly_json.so, libglog.so, libglog_init.so, libimagepipeline.so, libjsc.so, libjscexecutor.so, libjsi.so, libjsijniprofiler.so, libjsinspector.so, liblogger.so, libmapbufferjni.so, libnative-filters.so, libnative-imagetranscoder.so, libreact_codegen_rncore.so, libreact_config.so, libreact_debug.so, libreact_nativemodule_core.so, libreact_render_animations.so, libreact_render_attributedstring.so, libreact_render_componentregistry.so, libreact_render_core.so, libreact_render_debug.so, libreact_render_graphics.so, libreact_render_imagemanager.so, libreact_render_leakchecker.so, libreact_render_mapbuffer.so, libreact_render_mounting.so, libreact_render_runtimescheduler.so, libreact_render_scheduler.so, libreact_render_telemetry.so, libreact_render_templateprocessor.so, libreact_render_textlayoutmanager.so, libreact_render_uimanager.so, libreact_utils.so, libreactnativeblob.so, libreactnativejni.so, libreactnativeutilsjni.so, libreactperfloggerjni.so, librrc_image.so, librrc_root.so, librrc_text.so, librrc_unimplementedview.so, librrc_view.so, libruntimeexecutor.so, libturbomodulejsijni.so, libyoga.so.
```

The build is successfull and the app works, but when I build the apk with command `./gradlew assembleRelease` in android folder, I have this warning:

```
Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                    Welcome to Metro!
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


info Writing bundle output to:, C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle
info Writing sourcemap output to:, C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\generated\sourcemaps\react\release\index.android.bundle.map
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 1 asset files
info Done copying assets

> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\navigation_json\release\navigation.json'. Reason: Task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
[androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0] C:\Users\emanu\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\60134c6b86acadc5685250a34382945d\transformed\vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
        Package name 'androidx.vectordrawable' used in: androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0, androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1.

> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:processReleaseManifest' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\compatible_screen_manifest\release'. Reason: Task ':app:processReleaseManifest' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml'. Reason: Task ':app:processReleaseManifest' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets                                                                                       
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:compressReleaseAssets' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\mergeReleaseAssets'. Reason: Task ':app:compressReleaseAssets' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:sdkReleaseDependencyData
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:sdkReleaseDependencyData' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\metadata_library_dependencies_report\release\dependencies.pb'. Reason: Task ':app:sdkReleaseDependencyData' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:mergeReleaseJavaResource' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\java_res\release\out'. Reason: Task ':app:mergeReleaseJavaResource' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:processReleaseManifestForPackage' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release'. Reason: Task ':app:processReleaseManifestForPackage' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_jni_libs\release\out'. Reason: Task ':app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out'. Reason: Task ':app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libbutter.so, libc++_shared.so, libfabricjni.so, libfb.so, libfbjni.so, libfolly_futures.so, libfolly_json.so, libglog.so, libglog_init.so, libimagepipeline.so, libjsc.so, libjscexecutor.so, libjsi.so, libjsijniprofiler.so, libjsinspector.so, liblogger.so, libmapbufferjni.so, libnative-filters.so, libnative-imagetranscoder.so, libreact_codegen_rncore.so, libreact_config.so, libreact_debug.so, libreact_nativemodule_core.so, libreact_render_animations.so, libreact_render_attributedstring.so, libreact_render_componentregistry.so, libreact_render_core.so, libreact_render_debug.so, libreact_render_graphics.so, libreact_render_imagemanager.so, libreact_render_leakchecker.so, libreact_render_mapbuffer.so, libreact_render_mounting.so, libreact_render_runtimescheduler.so, libreact_render_scheduler.so, libreact_render_telemetry.so, libreact_render_templateprocessor.so, libreact_render_textlayoutmanager.so, libreact_render_uimanager.so, libreact_utils.so, libreactnativeblob.so, libreactnativejni.so, libreactnativeutilsjni.so, libreactperfloggerjni.so, librrc_image.so, librrc_root.so, librrc_text.so, librrc_unimplementedview.so, librrc_view.so, libruntimeexecutor.so, libturbomodulejsijni.so, libyoga.so.

> Task :app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out'. Reason: Task ':app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\stripped_native_libs\release\out'. Reason: Task ':app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libbutter.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.        
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfabricjni.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfb.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfbjni.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfolly_futures.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.     
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libfolly_json.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.        
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libglog.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the arm64-v8a ABI.


Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreactnativeutilsjni.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.     
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreactperfloggerjni.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.      
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_codegen_rncore.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.    
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_config.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_debug.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_nativemodule_core.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI. 
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_animations.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI. 
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_attributedstring.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_componentregistry.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_core.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.       
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_debug.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.      
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_graphics.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.   
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_imagemanager.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_leakchecker.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_mapbuffer.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.  
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_mounting.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.   
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_runtimescheduler.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_scheduler.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.  
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_telemetry.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.  
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_templateprocessor.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_textlayoutmanager.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_render_uimanager.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.  
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libreact_utils.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\librrc_image.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\librrc_root.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\librrc_text.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\librrc_unimplementedview.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.   
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\librrc_view.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libruntimeexecutor.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libturbomodulejsijni.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.       
Unable to extract native debug metadata from C:\Users\emanu\App\rn8\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libyoga.so because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.

> Task :app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath have the version 1.4, which is older than the API version 1.5. Consider using the runtime of version 1.5, or pass '-api-version 1.4' explicitly to restrict the available APIs to the runtime of version 1.4. You can also pass '-language-version 1.4' instead, which will restrict not only the APIs to the specified version, but also the language features
w: C:\Users\emanu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.4.10\998caa30623f73223194a8b657abd2baec4880ea\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5
w: C:\Users\emanu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.4.10\30e46450b0bb3dbf43898d2f461be4a942784780\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.10.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5
w: C:\Users\emanu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.4.10\ea29e063d2bbe695be13e9d044dcfb0c7add398e\kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5
w: C:\Users\emanu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.4.10\6229be3465805c99db1142ad75e6c6ddeac0b04c\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.10.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5

> Task :app:lintVitalReportRelease
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath have the version 1.4, which is older than the API version 1.5. Consider using the runtime of version 1.5, or pass '-api-version 1.4' explicitly to restrict the available APIs to the runtime of version 1.4. You can also pass '-language-version 1.4' instead, which will restrict not only the APIs to the specified version, but also the language features
w: C:\Users\emanu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.4.10\998caa30623f73223194a8b657abd2baec4880ea\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5
w: C:\Users\emanu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.4.10\30e46450b0bb3dbf43898d2f461be4a942784780\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.10.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5
w: C:\Users\emanu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.4.10\ea29e063d2bbe695be13e9d044dcfb0c7add398e\kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5
w: C:\Users\emanu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.4.10\6229be3465805c99db1142ad75e6c6ddeac0b04c\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.10.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

The build is successfull and the apk is created, but when I install the apk in the device and start app, this crash imediatally
I don't know how fix it.
I am using v16.15.0 of nodejs, and this is the output when I run `java -version`

```
openjdk version "11.0.14.1" 2022-02-08
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.14.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.14.1+1, mixed mode)
```

react-native version: 0.68.1

any help is welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this helped me to solve the problem

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29398#issuecomment-708545702

```
//Fix for bundle not getting included in APK or AAB with android gradle plugin 4+
//Seems like there's a task ordering issue and the assets get computed before the bundle is copied
//This forces the copy task to run before merge resources
project.afterEvaluate {
        tasks.findAll { task ->
            task.name.startsWith('merge') && task.name.endsWith('Resources')
        }.each { t -> t.dependsOn "copyReleaseBundledJs" }
}
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29398

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/30177

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/53f55001afbf07494de0df064a92dfdd42f37c98

Answer (score -1):

Try to clean the gradlew folder before building your app.
Run following command on your terminal inside the root directory of your project.

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && gradlew assembleDebug && cd ..
```

If it's not working you might forgot to link your dependencies to android folder, run the following command on your terminal inside your root directory of your app:

```
react-native link
```

Comment: If I run ./gradlew assembleDebug I have the error "Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libbutter.so, libc++_ ..." and if I run ./gradlew assembleRelease I have the errors described in the post. Same thing if I link the dependencies